# what is the meaning of == sign?

Tags: c, syntax, operators

I am trying to figure out what == sign means in this program?

```
int main()
{
    int x = 2, y = 6, z = 6;        
    x = y == z;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: Well, what does it print? What does it print for other values of `y` and `z` (and `x`, for completeness)?

Comment: It's clearer to understand if written like this: x=(y==z);

Comment: In your example, since `y` is equal to `z`, it will print `1`. If `y` is not equal to `z`, it will print `0`.

Comment: guess this is homework, since we have seen the exact same bad example code some days ago, don't we?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `==` operator tests for equality. For example:

```
if ( a == b )
    dosomething();
```

And, in your example:

```
x = y == z;
```

x is true (1) if y is equal to z. If y is *not* equal to z, x is false (0).

A common mistake made by novice C programmers (and a typo made by some very experienced ones as well) is:

```
if ( a = b )
    dosomething();
```

In this case, b is assigned to a then evaluated as a boolean expression. Sometimes a programmer will do this deliberately but it's bad form. Another programmer reading the code won't know if it was done intentionally (rarely) or inadvertently (much more likely). A better construct would be:

```
if ( (a = b) == 0 )   // or !=
    dosomething();
```

Here, b is assigned to a, then the result is compared with 0. The intent is clear. (Interestingly, I've worked with C# programmers who have never written pure C and couldn't tell you what this does.)

Comment: For completeness, the value of `y == z` is either 1 or 0.  So "x is true (non-zero)..." is better replaced with "`x` is 1 ...".

Comment: That is true but it wasn't always true. I started with C before the ANSI standard existed. K&R didn't specify the result of relational operators other than to say they determine the "truth or falsehood of the result" (p. 38). They _do_ go on to say that the "unary negation operator ! converts a non-zero or true operand into 0, and a 0 or false operand into 1." Since K&R was the only standard at the time, I learned not to make assumptions about the results of boolean expressions. Draft ANSI C (X3.159.198x) fixed this in "3.3.8 Relational operators" and "3.3.9 Equality operators."

Comment: `int war = 0; if (war = 1) { launchnuke(); }` unforgivable typo.

Answer (score 5):

It is "equals" operator.

In the above example, `x` is assigned the result of equality test (`y == z`) expression. So, if `y` is equal to `z`, `x` will be set to `1` (true), otherwise `0` (false). Because C (pre-C99) does not have a boolean type, the expression evaluates to an integer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but off the top of my head C99 *does* have a boolean type via. `stdbool.h` - it's an actual compiler supported type, not just an `int` or `enum` (`(int) true == 1` still holds, though). Devs do not have to use it.

Comment: @delty, probably should clarify that I mean C89.

Comment: @detly: It's named `_Bool`. The name alone is probably enough to reduce excessive usage …

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig - the type name reserved for compiler use is `_Bool`, but every header I've ever seen has `#define bool _Bool` — I don't know if that's mandated by the standard though. Also, I discovered that my statement above is misleading — `true` is just a `#define` and does not have a compiler-recognised type.

Comment: @detly: No, the standard defines the type `_Bool`, *as the type to be used by the user* (6.2.5.2). It also defines that `<stdbool.h>` defines the *macro* `bool` to expand to `_Bool` (which then is still the name appearing in error messages and warnings. Clause 7.1.3.1 makes `_Bool` a reserved identifier, but that does not mean a program should not use it – it means a program is not allowed to introduce a definition for this name itself. The goal is to have a name space for compiler writeres *and* future standard extensions. (The names `_Complex` and `_Imaginary` are meant for the user, too.)

Comment: Oh, and the standard explicitly says that undefining `bool`, `true`, and `false` is fine, while changing `_Bool` leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Equality. It returns 1 if the operands are equal, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

== means "is euual to". This operator has higher precedece than = (equal to) operator. So the equation  x = y == z; will try to assign result of y==z to variable x. which is 1 in this case.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning precedence. Another potential minefield for novice C programmers. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() 
{ 
    int x = 2, y = 6, z = 6;         
    x = y == z; 
    printf("%d", x); 
}
```

let`s start like this:

```
 x = (6==6)
```

It asks is 6 equivalent to 6?: true

x = true, but since x is an int, x= 1
The new value of x is 1.

### The following is printed:

1

Answer (score 0):

It's saying

> X will equal either true/1 or false/0.

another way to look at that line is this:

```
x =  ( is y equal to true? then true/1 or false/0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

== operator used for equality..
here in u r example
if y is equal to z then x will hav true value otherwise x will hav false

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this:

= means give something a value.

== means check if it is equal to a value.

For example

```
int val = 5; //val is 5
//= actually changes val to 3
val = 3; 

//== Tests if val is 3 or not. 
//note: it DOES NOT CHANGE the value of val.
val == 3; 

int new_val = val == 3; //new_val will be 1, because the test is true

//the above statement is the same as
bool is_val_3 = false;
if( val == 3 )
   is_val_3 = true;
int new_val;
new_val = is_val_3;

//putting it together, 
val = new_val == 2; //sets val to 0. do you understand why now?
```